# Sequelize creates extra column when defining associations with alias in Postgresql

Tags: sequelize.js

When I define associations that use an alias, Sequelize creates the columns with the alias as expected, but also creates an extra column with the name of the model: FromTileId, ToTileID, TileId.

Using Sequelize ^6.29.3 with Postgresql, I've initialized all my models as classes, as shown in the docs:

```js
    class Tile extends Model {

    }

    Tile.init({
        x: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        },
        y: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        sequelize: fastify.sequelize
    });
```

After all models are initialized, I set all associations in one file:

```js
    const { Gamesave, March, Tile, User } = fastify.sequelize.models;


    //adds userId to Gamesave
    User.hasOne(Gamesave);
    Gamesave.belongsTo(User);

    //adds fromTileId to March
    Tile.hasOne(March, { as: 'FromTile', foreignKey: 'FromTileId' });

    //adds toTileId to March
    Tile.hasOne(March, { as: 'ToTile', foreignKey: 'ToTileId' });
    March.belongsTo(Tile);
```

Associations without an alias produce the expected columns after syncing, with Gamesaves having a UserId column.

Associations with an alias produce the expected columns, along with an unexpected column:

```
    FromTileId
    ToTileId
    TileId
```

The code I used in this question to create multiple assocations involving the same model is directly from the Sequelize docs [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#multiple-associations-involving-the-same-models), though this happens with any association with an alias.

I've tried several variations of assigning the alias, both the alias and the foreign key, and it seems the `.belongsTo()` method is creating the extra column. For some associations, it's fine to only be able to include associations from one of the models, but not all.

How can I implement associations with aliases, using both the pairs `hasOne()` or `hasMany()` with `belongsTo()` so that I can include the associated model from either, without getting these extra columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't indciate `foreginKey` option in `March.belongsTo(Tile)` explicitly that's why Sequelize creaetd a default one `TileId`.
You need to define two associations from `March` to `Tile` with exact `foreignKey` options and values (not the aliases) like you did for two `Tile` to `March` associations because for each association and each unique `foreignKey` option value Sequelize creates a foreign key.

```js
 //adds fromTileId to March
    Tile.hasOne(March, { as: 'FromMarch', foreignKey: 'FromTileId' });
    //adds toTileId to March
    Tile.hasOne(March, { as: 'ToMarch', foreignKey: 'ToTileId' });

    March.belongsTo(Tile, { as: 'FromTile', foreignKey: 'FromTileId' });
    March.belongsTo(Tile, { as: 'ToTile', foreignKey: 'ToTileId' });
```

Remember that an alias in an association is for naming a model that is passed as the first argument and **not** for the model which `belongsTo/hasOne` method you call.

Comment: Thank you! I'd tried something similar but must've messed up the foreign keys or something.