# Unwanted column is created while creating One-To-Many association using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm using Sqlite as database and Node.js and Sequelize as backend in my project. I have the following models:

**message.model.js:**

```
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize');

const messageSchema = {
    message_Id: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true,unique: true },
    msg_serial: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    sender_user_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    target_user_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    message_detail: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
    delivered: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false },
    is_seen: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false }
};

module.exports = {messageSchema}
```

**request.model.js:**

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const requestSchema = {
    request_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
    sender_user_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    target_user_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    is_seen: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, default: false },
    is_accepted: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, default: false }
}

module.exports = { requestSchema };
```

**role.model.js:**

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const roleSchema = [{
    role_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
    role_name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }
}, { timestamps: false }]

module.exports = { roleSchema }
```

**user.model.js:**

```
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize');

const userSchema = {
    user_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
    username: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    password: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    last_update: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: true },
    profile_image: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true },
    lastVisitAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: true },
    is_locked: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: true },
    lock_until: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: true },
    is_banned: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: true },
    createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false },
    updatedAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: true },
    socket_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: true },
    roleRef: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false }
}

module.exports = {userSchema}
```

**context.js:**

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const { userSchema } = require('./user.model');
const { messageSchema } = require('./message.model');
const { roleSchema } = require('./role.model');
const { requestSchema } = require('./request.model');

var connection;

(async function () {
    if (!connection) {
        //Initialize connection on the first run
        connection = new Sequelize({
            dialect: 'sqlite',
            storage: 'LinkChat.sqlite'
        });
        try {
            await connection.authenticate();
            console.log("Database Connection has been established successfully.")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Unable to connect to the database.", error);
        }
    }

    CreateTables();
})();

async function CreateTables() {
    //Create the tables
    try {
        await connection.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
            console.log("Created the tables successfully.");
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Cannot create the tables.\n" + error);
    }
    initialRole();
    initialUser();
}

const User = connection.define("Users", userSchema);

const Role = connection.define("Roles", roleSchema[0], roleSchema[1]);

const Message = connection.define("Messages", messageSchema);

const Request = connection.define("Requests", requestSchema);

User.belongsTo(Role, {
    foreignKey: "roleRef",
    targetKey: "role_id"
});

User.hasMany(Message, { as: "Messages" });

Message.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "sender_user_id",
    targetKey: "user_id"
});

Message.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "target_user_id",
    targetKey: "user_id"
});

User.hasMany(Request, { as: "Requests" });

Request.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "sender_user_id",
    targetKey: "user_id"
});

Request.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "target_user_id",
    targetKey: "user_id"
});

function initialRole() {
    Role.create({
        role_name: 'developer'
    });
    Role.create({
        role_name: 'admin'
    });
    Role.create({
        role_name: 'user'
    });
}


module.exports = { connection, Sequelize, models: { userTable: User, roleTable: Role, messageTable: Message, requestTable: Request } }
```

The problem is that when the tables are created, there are two unwanted `UserUserId` columns in `Messages` and `Requests` tables.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to indicate the same `foreignKey` options for all paired associations (belognsTo/asMany for instance) and different aliases in case you pair the same tables twice:

```
User.hasMany(Message, { as: "SentMessages", foreignKey: "sender_user_id" });
User.hasMany(Message, { as: "ReceivedMessages", foreignKey: "target_user_id" });

Message.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "sender_user_id",
    as: 'Sender'
});

Message.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "target_user_id",
    as: 'Receiver'
});

User.hasMany(Request, { as: "SentRequests", foreignKey: "sender_user_id" });
User.hasMany(Request, { as: "ReceivedRequests", foreignKey: "target_user_id" });

Request.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "sender_user_id"
});

Request.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "target_user_id"
});
```

Also there is no need to indicate `targetKey` if its value points to PK field.

See my other [answer to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75782983/1376618)

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and for the question that led me here). I faced the same issue and spent hours going back and forth to Sequelize documentation and here in SO without any success. The answer explains the reason of the problem and the solution very neatly.